# How to calculate weekly and monthly (OHLCV) table from daily table (OHLCV) SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need help to how to calculate weekly and monthly (OHLCV) table from daily table (OHLCV)

```
o open
h high
l low
c close
v volume-(such as number of trade or value of trade)
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Answer (score 0):

```
[THIS IS MY DATABASE BACKUP][1]


  [1]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=193sNemJKmfuN8vk-e2iQWCLnj6EOwy3V
AND SQL QUERY:
select [<SYMBOL>],[YEAR], [MONTH],
    max([Open]) as [OPEN],max([HIGH]) as [HIGH], min([LOW]) as [LOW],
     max([Close]) as [CLOSE], SUM([VOLUME]) as [VOLUME]
from (
    select 
        [<SYMBOL>],
        Datepart(year, [<DATE>]) AS [YEAR],  
        Datepart(month, [<DATE>]) AS [MONTH], 
        max([<High>]) over( 
            partition by
                [<SYMBOL>],
                Datepart(year, [<DATE>]) ,  
                Datepart(month, [<DATE>])
            ) as [HIGH], 
        min([<Low>]) over( 
            partition by
                [<SYMBOL>],
                Datepart(year, [<DATE>]) ,  
                Datepart(month, [<DATE>])
            ) as [LOW],
        first_value([<OPEN>]) over( 
            partition by
                [<SYMBOL>],
                Datepart(year, [<DATE>]) ,  
                Datepart(month, [<DATE>])
            order by
                [<SYMBOL>],
                Datepart(year, [<DATE>]) ,  
                Datepart(month, [<DATE>])
            ) as [Open],
        last_value([<CLOSE>]) over( 
            partition by
                [<SYMBOL>],
                Datepart(year, [<DATE>]) ,  
                Datepart(month, [<DATE>])
            order by
                [<SYMBOL>],
                Datepart(year, [<DATE>]) ,  
                Datepart(month, [<DATE>])
            ) as [Close],
            SUM([<VOLUME>]) over( 
            partition by
                [<SYMBOL>],
                Datepart(year, [<DATE>]) ,  
                Datepart(month, [<DATE>])
            ) as [VOLUME]
    from [stock].[dbo].[daily] ) T
group by [<SYMBOL>],[YEAR], [MONTH]
ORDER BY [<SYMBOL>],[YEAR], [MONTH]
------
ALL IS OK BUT VOLUME IS MISTAKE
PLZ HELP ME
```